# Cheeky regex help: substring or match numerical part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
foo = "$22.50 + taxes"
```

I want 22.50.

Tried:

```
foo.match(/^\$([^\ +])/)
```

My flawed logic? "Start with dollar sign then go as far back as many characters that are not `" +"` then return that.

How do I get the number part only? Assume the actual number, 22.5 is a variable and could be anything, but the text surrounding it will be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to a match `$` and number:

```
foo.match(/^\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/)
//=> ["$22.50"]
```

OR using lookahead to match from `$` until you get `" +"`:

```
foo.match(/^\$.*(?= \+)/)
//=> ["$22.50"]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Really like the look ahead method

Comment: Was testing this lookback method on another string but am struggling. Can you see what's up with my attempts? var fr = "1 staff basic cadeau d’une valeur de 22,50 $ taxes en sus"
Tried: fr.match(/^de .*(?= \$)/), fr.match(/^de .*(?= )/) and a few others. All return null?

Comment: `fr.match(/^.*(?= \$)/)` will give you a match. `fr.match(/^de.*(?= \$)/)` is not working because your input is not starting with `de`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to anchor the regexp at the beginning, or match a dollar sign, or match following space and plus sign. Just grab the sequence of numbers and period:

```
foo.match(/[\d.]+/)

> ["22.50"]
```

Comment: "You paid me only $22.50...", "Section 1.2.3", etc.

Comment: *but the text surrounding it will be consistent*.